# Exclude subtypes from SQL Query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have the Linq query below:

```
var result = (from booking in _context.Booking.AsNoTracking()
  join vendor in _context.Vendor.AsNoTracking() on booking.VendorId equals vendor.Id
  where
    booking.ClientId == userId 
  orderby booking.Id descending
  select vendor.TypeId).FirstOrDefault();
```

A Vendor can be subtyped into a Mobile or a Garage.
But for my use case, I don't care about the subtype.

The SQL that is generated includes the subtype tables with a UNION.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project3].[TypeId] AS [TypeId]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Join1].[TypeId] AS [TypeId]
        FROM  [dbo].[Booking] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN  (SELECT [UnionAll1].[VendorId] AS [VendorId], [Extent4].[TypeId] AS [TypeId]
            FROM   (SELECT 
                [Extent2].[VendorId] AS [VendorId]
                FROM [dbo].[Garage] AS [Extent2]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                [Extent3].[VendorId] AS [VendorId]
                FROM [dbo].[Mobile] AS [Extent3]) AS [UnionAll1]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Vendor] AS [Extent4] ON [UnionAll1].[VendorId] = [Extent4].[Id] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[VendorId] = [Join1].[VendorId]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ClientId] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Project3]
    ORDER BY [Project3].[Id] DESC',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0='6AE9C275-7944-47B0-9B03-7B10EC88C98C'
```

This is wasteful.
How can I exclude the SubTypes from being included in the SQL command?

Bonus question.
Can I make the TOP 1 run in the nested SQL?
Again. This is wasteful. It gets a full result first, and then TOP 1s it.

Comment: Looks like you have used TPT (Table Per Type) and such hierarchy should have base class (Table) which you can use while building query.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - The base class is Vendor, which is being used in the LINQ statement. In the LINQ there is no mention of "Garage" or "Mobile", but they do appear on the SQL.

Comment: Try `join vendor in _context.Vendor.OfType<Vendor>()`

Comment: I removed the linq-to-sql tag. That's not EF. Please add a tag for the EF version you use.

Comment: That's just ow EF generates the SQL. Nothing you can do about it.